# Keep rig feet flat on the ground (IK Rig)

Tags: rigging, constraints, inverse-kinematics

So I have an IK rig setup; however, when I move the pelvis down to make the character squat the feet fall through the ground. e.g.[image: Example]

How can I set it up so that when I move the pelvis down the feet stay flat and do not rotate beneath the surface of the ground?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to select the foot bones and uncheck the "Inherit Rotation" option.

[image]

Another interesting foot behaviour can be achieved parenting the Foot bone to the LegIK bone instead of Shin (and leaving the "Inherit Rotation" Checked).

Anyway the foot rigging is one of the most complex situation in human rigging; so, to improve your leg, you can type "How to rig a leg" on Google and find tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U3NjTvwdWI.

Comment: This works. However, the armour no longer moves with the foot. The heel pushes through the armour when moving the pelvis down

Comment: If I apply the same thing to the heels it works, cheers :)